# Manage discriminated unions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

## Enums Won't Work

TypeScript enums come close to what I need, but they don't get all the way there. I need a **known-at-compile-time** and **static-at-runtime** set of items that act like an enum, but are instances of a class to enable adding functionality such as properties or methods.

Assume TypeScript 4.4.3 for the purposes of this question.

## Example

As an example, say a small convenience store has three aisles. Each aisle has an `id` and a `name`:

```
// Aisle objects
name: 'food', aisleId: '4'
name: 'housewares', aisldId: '7'
name: 'camping', aisleId: '9'
```

When the `name` or `aisleId` of an aisle is contained in a variable, some static helper methods on the `Aisles` class make sense:

```
static getByName(name: string): Aisle {
  // return the right Aisle, or return undefined, or maybe throw
}

static getById(aisleId: string): Aisle {
  // same, but for aisleId
}
```

(There might be a `description` property, and others, but there won't be any lookup on Aisle objects by description.)

If some code wants to work with a particular `Aisle`, it would be nice to just write `Aisles.Food`, or `Aisles['7']`. While the above `getBy` methods could be used, it's not wonderful to have to use `Aisles.getById('food')` when `'food'` is known at compile-time. If those have to be in different enums such as `AisleNames.Food` or `AisleIds['7']`, that would be fine.

## Goals

It would be great to achieve all, or most, of these goals:

- Code that only works with passed-in `Aisle` instances should be able to rely on ambient declarations, without needing to import anything: `function cleanAisle(aisle: Aisle) {}` shouldn't have to import anything, because it's not creating any instances.
- An enum-like collection of all aisles can be exposed somewhere: `AisleList` perhaps. or `Aisles`. Or `AislesEnum`.
- Ambient type declarations canonically drive type-safety throughout the code base. It would not be great to need two potentially-conflicting sources of type/class information, one `.ts` file that exposes an enum or enum like object, and a separate one in an ambient `.d.ts` file that shadows the enum, with neither being the single canonical source.
- A type error should occur somewhere if there are any inconsistencies: if any bit of code has a new aisle added, or removed, or misnamed, or misspelled, or there are any duplicates where there shouldn't be.
- The scheme has the least possible amount of code repetition. E.g., it's not great to name a property, but pass that same name as a string into a constructor just so the class instance can be used to return its own name, e.g., `readonly food = new Aisle('food', '4')` repeats `'food'`. And this could suffer a mismatch between the property and the instance. Ideal would be `new Aisle<'food'>()` and then drive the actual `name` property or use of the name as a code symbol, everywhere, deriving from either the ambient type declaration or from the right instance of the class. (There is a TypeScript plugin to implement `nameof` at compile-time that might be helpful, but I haven't gotten that far yet.)

## My Attempts

In my attempts to achieve these goals, several problems showed up. (You can see [some of my noodling in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAgglgZwDYQHIEMC20C8UDkAZgPbEAm+UAPgQBbECuCEA7ugE4QKU34DGWMHAB2Ac3wAoCSOAR2hdH2jxk0AN4SoUTujLFhSEFGFYIALliIUGbJu0Rd+w1HRWIASTIWEwdiNF2OnoGRmRcfH5gwHD63r7+EgC+UnxI6AgIUADC+hEQsiooADwAKlAQAB6ywmSZhWimAHxQcJhgKNjCwHVuUBpafPo+7Ax8wMTsABRBTkYm2BYlADT2jiEubp5xfmIrM+thCBFwUTHC2-4AlH3Jdj7o0XxQAEYMcEhkRQCq5VUQNT1VDYII1JoMwhYvitXKotlBhv4VodjqdYvD4mJLhZ6n0oAB6PFQYC0RBQbDE8gtTIAKyYwCJxBcADdiHAyFBaOgmf4GVABD4XJkAAb1IVQfTlRS0KBC4SsSaXIV2LScYAMdjCYysbK5VUQepg8gQaGbMhI8KRaL6a7pSyqOzJW4EqAAeTlUDYRmIhCJ7BAPPGUDChBE0GJyjcmRYcApDHpnO5Yl5ehlJEpeDlLCgADpcwQ0xQlc6AEJxom0aAARwYXCtmu9HOIWcDCAYYDAE3pSBjcnQSF+YE4GTOmVbfGltpFkezBbFExl9QQAG18AAWfAAXXsmFcwky6Cg1drZw9MelxMQ2Ykgz39JhKAQAGV8lAM9rn8BJku7DlhHkCm42avO8ZCTEQpAUCsa74FBMBIP2F5iJkEBkHAzwoPglxLD+ur5PqgHAR8YECG0-gwQQADs5H4AAsugADW0AgIw7CNtgUAAF5kVhOF-nq9RAW8RHgeQ1EAJzUQA4i+MiMuG4pxnoEwIAAhJh2FaL+-74aogkgWBBbUQAjEZ1GPpAfBwH2oDwgwmDYKxPaYNwWH4oSwiMqIDAcOgXQQNADYMMIcBHnKGQvHMpgSBulwpEMd5uMCJTEPUdFgK+WpZmlRT1MCKz1KCMDsOw6AgDO7DEJgkz3lwH6XNmO5gNVvQ4M0S41dm8zGhsqgxdczoXlG7z9sQTJyCwfiyEGbbdgIsiZM8kXYCs0bEuW0BpAKohwGNmpMn2NbXvFPUoJ4yWpeg6Vvlll2TEVJVlYQFVVTVT75PVjXNaor5tR1NWeCavWXP1hKDae8HimN7ATT203tHAc1cBFLRmqea3yZt9LbbtUD7Ugh0SKAkB2g+ACiwh2b2dYZWoqzBM4S4ANItJquWmBu2K9IkbnGJ53klX5YYVgubhitGEPPELAXusSDxkg845I1OQKmEKKySwITBS7jB3QIgwj4PSyvFIzjRKqk6SAg+LRtB0-zdCTXDk5TJXU-0PMlCSmRgA8sgakGxBI3LKDpFj-O+bI0B9ghwt4zW+6cFAg5cPb0I1FAQUhTW6tljGUCEP5SCZKh7CgIEDj00YBYZVp-EEUJoEiZBBDrrBEOIaIyGoehECYeXazOPQWtsEONe4QBumEY3JFCGI1FUVBdGMVAzHqmx0BcXPIONsPHBIypOB4DPCQqhXsx8oIPJ4LXeECVPBkQfPUkyV0cnC4wwBKewqmYTzx9JgfPABY07smrqSTgkAHgoSJNGJQ2ZKKUFJAeMgM0EZQPFD6IezAR5cAALQUXgY+IeHwXjQHwBJHOd4uwOAFJnI8V47DOgAOqlQZIyTAoxpQVUqvneccgKqsQrJwfulcW6UDwINGcEERHn3wFRDKkisGsD3ggGR6xyHiPLJef+AQ7CiHyMWEAbNsBfWsKYTmKtsBYkdn0ZUPNVTqk1K9dqiV2Y8zBnoJGLAJj0UofYbsSMJTyRQfDOaO1oBCn2M4aueBczwKbvgMUPtgB+2EHYhx-sapJRSm4NK2Z9GfiyaYbetB2CYBWB2Yc6EjBCiCsGUMZA1blBxrGUQE5XHsVJPRDyLBNSBkli4TUxsGjYCaRrdAWt1pQDSgHLgBssbhMGUYLyPlBYuGeB-JOQ5-hKAdFILQBTDH1E8KYjwXh0Q7FENYnE7sBjHSHAwJA9I8D-TIOdXJl18n5FOZ4WKWgtBwB9JMFSDynnXFpsSCqWZMxQFJsVCYkwhSoEZGOdp31VpotOuyfAAASNQrzEj4GzEKa43NnTzgyZqOpEAQxynZPOA8fA6Q8JdKiEwSAijNCJhAK8-z7Bqn9qC4Aey7A+2-jpMxJiikLAuVcCxKBqAZxqDShpti+WAqgJMSRis+D0WMRAAAan2NkpzgTAzVXy-ljitHLmlRADcdjkh8spUq+pdKRUDArLq-VRruygQEDUNkUD9UXExBYANqEyDBo6XrK2Iz1DpPyNau17zVB5M5AgMEvlI3RssVHONZq9m3BvAKV6GUYWLgVBISoHZS5BhpRMp5J0uBSGdAgQQCqmDoH0XyI0cVbxBjgKXIxppMjXSgB+L80EYr9oFKkBwwh6iGM8BlH55yERhpeKQEOmpWoWo1ZMEuoBjm1GzBmtd5rbmDuHSehA2YwgoFkBexNAq+kjAgHs0+r7859mYEkWd9J52+RxHgU58qIDWI2cQHdP0+Q7qXSAE5f1TSxQkPdUq5VKqnLesAeqIYnlyDBPBtweGJikylKc2D7sS3QZ5UgYgohEVZB3dAmqaNpRdQIHijqXVEhqRJUkVDQHF1uGw9mHR29ux+z7PYAunA-wfuEwaZx+AACsm5t6iAgisGM+BMjdKbH0r2syEDzN+IgYAfj5Keg9NALT9JZb0lJDGZgSAfRHpANeYjqhsMrnXDOo6A6RBgDjCG2VSY8D4CUTg7ggWBTBdCy1Ztd6xXMH1ZMBLwB9WoaAA), but not everything I tried is in there.)

I tried adding a generic type parameter to `Aisle`, such as `Aisle<'food'>`, but when working to put those in a collection, how do I use an interface for them? E.g., given `interface Aisle<T extends AisleName> {}` and a concrete class `ConcreteAisle<T extends AisleName> implements Aisle<T> {}`, one can't put instances of `ConcreteAisle<T>` into `Aisle[]` because `Aisle` wants a generic type argument, but there is no single generic type to give that. Would a union work there, such as `Aisle<AisleName>` where `type AisleName = 'food' | 'housewares' | 'camping'`? Then the uniqueness/completeness problem rears its head. A `Set<Aisle>` won't guarantee uniqueness. Here's where "enums in TypeScript are not great" comes in.

`enum Aisle as const` could help, if only the code didn't require `"isolatedModules": true` in `tsconfig.json`. So that's not an option.

Also had some trouble with methods `getAisleById()` and `getAisleByName()`. Using a `Set` of `Aisle` objects, and doing a `.map()` over them in order to generate a `Map<AisleName, Aisle>` and a `Map` for `aisleId` ran into the problem that even if a type union is used for the passed-in value, the `Map<K, V>#get` method returns type `V | undefined`, requiring some kind of workaround to trick TypeScript into believing that the result is known to not be `undefined` so long as the value is in the union type. I know how to use functions that return `var is Type` as the return value, or `asserts var is Type`, but would rather not expose those to the consumers of these objects—that should all be internal to the implementation of `Aisles` and `Aisle` enum-like constructs, if possible.

If necessary, I could write a separate concrete class for each `Aisle`. that would be fine, and would let me hard-code the `aisleName` and `aisleId` in each one instead of having to pass those values into a constructor. But the "how to work with these in a collection that functions as a discriminated union" problem becomes worse.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting to dynamically modify this "enum" or union of aisles at runtime?

Comment: @j_m4rtinez No, the list is static at run-time!

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if your example code were a [mre] that showed the problems you're running into explicitly, preferably with errors in places where what you are trying to do isn't working.  Right now the word-to-code ratio is high enough that I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: @jcalz I did actually just add a TypeScript Playground example a few minutes ago. Is that what you're looking for, or do you think I should do something more?

Comment: That playground has no errors or comments that shows me what you expect vs what you got, so I'm forced to wade through it line at a time, code-review style.  Which takes a bunch of time I might not have to put into it.  I'm not saying you *have* to make this easier to consume, someone else might get here and have a better time with it... but lowering the bar to let others understand the issues you're facing might improve the chance of getting a good answer.  Could just be that I'm tired... ‍♂️

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save. I've added more comments. I'll keep trying to make it simpler. You're right, expecting others to invest a LOT is not reasonable.

Comment: @jcalz I'd thought I could save in-place, but I have to update the link here after a save. I'm doing that now.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N9Jkjm) meet your needs or am I missing some of the use cases?  It's kind of hard to tell what your module/export/import/ambient requirements are when we're using TS Playground; if you have some better web IDE project that does module stuff better I'd be happy to look at it.  Anyway if that meets your needs I can describe it and write it up as an answer; otherwise, uh, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I'm also not sure exactly what the requirements are and where the solutions you've tried fell short, but try this out: https://tsplay.dev/w6BgGw

Comment: I've added more comments and code to show how the playground example might be used. Will take a look at your solutions now!

Comment: @jcalz I don't know of a better way to share TypeScript code. Being able to define modules (with ambient types) would be a great improvement. Your code looks fantastic! You've clearly done this before. I like you how solved the uniqueness and completeness problems. I think your code is way closer to working than my attempts were. Let me play with that a bit.

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks for spending time on this! Did you catch in your example the duplicate `7` `aisleIds`?

Comment: P.S. I didn't know about tsplay.dev. Thanks! I might make a tampermonkey or greasemonkey extension to do that automatically. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, [`enum` values in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are really just primitive strings or numbers.  They don't behave like [`enum` in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) which are just class instances under the hood.  If you want enum-like class instances, you'll have to build them yourself.

One approach could be to not export the underlying class (so that new instances you don't control don't show up everywhere) and make sure they are strongly typed enough so that the resulting enums can behave as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) by having a literal-valued discriminant property.  Looks like you have two such properties, `name` and `aisleId`, so let's make this underlying `Aisle` class [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both of these:

```
class Aisle<N extends string, I extends string> {
    constructor(public name: N, public aisleId: I, public description: string) { }
    someMethod() {
        console.log("Hi, I'm " + this.name + " and my Id is " + 
          this.aisleId + " and my description is " + this.description);
    }
}
```

Since we want the exported `Aisles` enum-like object to have keys for each of these `name` and `aisleId` values, we can write a helper function which returns an object with both such keys where each value is the relevant class instance:

```
function make<N extends string, I extends string>(name: N, aisleId: I, description: string) {
    const aisle = new Aisle(name, aisleId, description);
    return { [name]: aisle, [aisleId]: aisle } as Record<N | I, typeof aisle>;
}
```

Note that the return type has to be [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as `Record<N | I, typeof aisle>` because the compiler unfortunately widens computed property key types all the way to `string`; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).

Now we can build our exported `Aisles` enum object thing with object spreading:

```
export const Aisles = {
    ...make("food", "4", 'All things edible'),
    ...make("housewares", "7", 'Make your home zing'),
    ...make("camping", "9", 'Get into the outdoors!')
} as const;
```

You can inspect `Aisles` to check that it has all the keys and values you care about.

```
/* const Aisles: {
    readonly camping: Aisle<"camping", "9">;
    readonly 9: Aisle<"camping", "9">;
    readonly housewares: Aisle<"housewares", "7">;
    readonly 7: Aisle<"housewares", "7">;
    readonly food: Aisle<...>;
    readonly 4: Aisle<...>;
} */
```

If you want `Aisles` to also be a type corresponding to the values of the `Aisles` object, (`enum`s do this automatically), you can do that:

```
export type Aisles = typeof Aisles[keyof typeof Aisles];
```

If you want to attach more types to `Aisles` you can do it [via a `namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing); for example, the `Name` and `Id` types corresponding to the union of relevant keys:

```
namespace Aisles {
    export type Name = Aisles extends infer A ? A extends Aisle<infer N, any> ? N : never : never;
    export type Id = Aisles extends infer A ? A extends Aisle<any, infer I> ? I : never : never;
}

export default Aisles
```

---

That's has, I hope, most of the features you care about.  You can access the `name` and `aisleId` keys of `Aisles`:

```
Aisles.food.someMethod(); 
// "Hi, I'm food and my Id is 4 and my description is All things edible"
Aisles[7].someMethod(); 
// "Hi, I'm housewares and my Id is 7 and my description is Make your home zing"
```

You can use the `Aisles` type as a discriminated union:

```
function processAisle(aisle: Aisles) {
    switch (aisle.name) {
        case "camping": return 0;
        case "food": return 1;
        // not all paths return a value unless you uncomment next line
        /* case "housewares": return 2; */
    }
}
```

You can use the exported `Aisles.Name` type to constrain keys to just the `name` and not the `aisleId` properties:

```
function reImplementGetAisleByName<N extends Aisles.Name>(name: N) {
    return Aisles[name]
}
const camping = reImplementGetAisleByName("camping");
// const camping: Aisle<"camping", "9">
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.4.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECCCWEQFMA8A5ayAeAXZAdgCYwS4BO8BA5gDTQCSWehJ0ZlNAfNAN4CwAKGgjowAPYEOAV2C5x5ABQAHaQCMQ8YNAJgAtsgBc0dPVUat0MIhQMixhmfWbtRZBGCVlueJOMcqagBKPmgAXyFRdnEDAFlkXAALcSJFEIFhKNEJKXEUADoQcWpFACIACXh6BgByPWhS6ABqaCTEfN0DZoarYmg9AE9GImhEHpa2iHzrJGQ7bsawPsHoNw8vH0lRmEaJxPa1z3hvXwIggG5I0QjBG4AzaQI5U-6wAGs0TBx8YlIKQOqzB+bAC3EUnSMJnoM1s9kY9EOG1O-n+NHSVxEOTIVhsyGgAF4dMgAO5wXHg-TIaG4uwI9xHE6SC4Y6DkBLScgEUIAbQhAF1jDCqdBuUK7AKcbNwlYYAAlZASchEDDQAA+8NaA2UyHEd0lKC4l1uQiEOGUClwYkk2IQsxghIyUXyzr072QZTu4hSpXopQALD7oDVYCAQK19jQYMgiPANMgakFaCznflXR8yslpBASWA2RBA6UAOyBmqxN3QAbiDnQZJdABegQTScyIhTafdpWA+mUgQLAE4SwBxBKjAjycN4qu4Ihe8gQACECaEYRlVqkuCNQgA9AAqNc23EQYyO0RssAzgggIZdvQ9mjGW0oVCd7u930Dw0ss8Xq-QPsP3FnxvO9qH7UpPxbVlkHPSRf0zbNiVzdwANmZ94JzPMC2LCCom-WChkLFCn1KdDEMw31sKNXDoJ-IZPRSIi0BTHDTxo-DoD9RjUGYo0Vx3LcTUEM0LU1bUyTtAlRJ1PVH3cbkPkrPVcC1aTxJQCA+SNCEIGUMBgDxWSYBPERhPIS1lLE9BKUkwygVYGAqDuZByDgaAAH5XO+ey1LQRznKhXoBh4DzMGMAhkAAN38sLIucqjRFM8yVOGGzDzs35RyclzYHczyWAy2TUCWAZ6D8lyGGCxhoBiqKXJquLl1NbBzTM1ZkDuMBpBAS1DME7ctwGwahuGkbRoEwRBMM-J6KIfIIBiZB4iSFI0nOaABoaSpqjqaAZt6EYVnmMY-X2-ohkRY5Ni5MYQzDNpIywGM41KIRDO5Qs+TmhaluSVILnWrdNqqRgdtIpCYCWA6hiOmBC1OlYLsZa6YDLD4KyrFzazxBsaBeibBAeJ4rugZRyHEfSoFkxQhUYiB0UgiBiXgXBgESaBqdxDpKXprJskgPEX1vXtjDZXAOS5AAGeLea7bMGhm0oRfZTloAARmlrJdzEfmGjBzClbFlWACY1v4lkbhuIRCeeLY2QYW8UAMMdh1wWSACEBisgwVS8grD3yL3kC4CkDGMdAedYw2uTe-lGsELFLWAwJJLth3kCd3AXfdz3KTKJPceZQQNoT7WhfvHygNfXH33AoQgA)

Comment: This is great stuff and I learned a lot. The one thing that I'm still left wanting is the ability to use `Aisle` as an ambient declaration (meaning a variable that accepts any instance of the `Aisle` class within a module that needs no import to do this). The part about doing `Aisle.NamedIsle` to actually refer to such an instance with an import required is right on track. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I think I figured out one way to do it. Create an `aisles.types.d.ts` file. In it, do `import type { Aisles from 'aisles.ts'` and then `declare global { type Aisle = Aisles }` and then use `Aisle` in an ambient context. You'll see `type Aisle = Aisle<"food", "4"> | Aisle <"camping", "9'> | ...`. This does add these types to the global context (though you can intersperse a namespace in there if desired).

Answer (score 1):

To be able to discriminate over a union of types, there must be at least one common property between the types that has a literal value (boolean, string, number, or unique symbol). You were on the right path by adding a `T extends ...` property to your `Aisle`.

Here is a possible approach that pulls out both the `id` and the `name` parameters from your `Aisle` class for maximum compile-time inferabilty:

```js
// `id` and `name` will both be pulled out as constants here, allowing you to get
// their exact values later on.
class Aisle<Id extends number, N extends string> {
  constructor(readonly id: Id, readonly name: N) { }
}

// Here's an "enum" of statically known Aisles
const Aisles = {
  1: new Aisle(1, 'baking'),
  2: new Aisle(2, 'garden'),
  3: new Aisle(3, 'spices'),
  4: new Aisle(4, 'food'),
  5: new Aisle(5, 'toys'),
  6: new Aisle(6, 'cleaning'),
  7: new Aisle(7, 'housewares'),
  8: new Aisle(8, 'travel'),
  9: new Aisle(9, 'camping'),
} as const; // Don't forget this

// And here's a type that makes referencing specific Aisles easier
type Aisles = typeof Aisles;

// Like so
type AisleOneOrTwo = Aisles[1] | Aisles[2];

// Accessing a particular Aisle
const a0 = Aisles[1] // Aisle<1, "baking">

// Fields are resolved to their literal values here.
a0.id // 1
a0.name // "baking"

// Here's a full union type of your Aisles.
type AislesUnion = Aisles[keyof Aisles];
```

Here's a [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAMEsBN1BDAdtCj4FsCmcDukA2+oARgPYAuAFiZqAA4CuhmKpD5CAzqAMamKdySct0qYATpgA0CQqTyIA5qACebUOVKhFmcgCgQGsZHGhMAD3g8OAN3j4GmbvnjkJofgDo9PF524AgpCc+JgAPACSKBZuyNyIDOjEEjIAcmbmsdDcguKQSgB8oADeeqC8-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-HoRGeMMtCGJsf5wpswGLMsGbwKABxMEQDCIJA-A9rQfaqGwphdt4w6dq+ACiuzPpuC6XJgaj9q+u6JomQA) as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for spending time on my question! I really should have spent more time writing comments and sample usage code in the TypeScript Playground before posting, because there are a few use cases I'd like to support. In the code here, it's definitely unexpected to use `Aisles[0]` to refer to an `Aisle` with `aisleId` of  `'1`. And `aisleId` values are not contiguous.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use an object literal with number indexes instead. This allows for the flexibility you're looking for here. Let me know if that works!